# Max number of records in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm writing a script that saves a CSV into a dynamoDB table. I'm using Node.js and the aws-sdk module. Everything seems to be correct, but I'm sending over 50k records to Dynamo, while only 1181 are saved and shown on the web console.

I've tried with different amount of records and this is the biggest count I get ,no matter if I try saving 100k, 10k or 50k.
According to AWS's documentation, there shouldn't be any limit to the  amount of records, any idea as to what other factors could influence this hard limit?

BTW, my code is catching errors from the insert actions, and I'm not picking up any when inserting past the 1181 mark, so the module is not really helping.

Any extra idea would be appreciated.

Comment: You've created a duplicate `dynamodb` tag - `amazon-dynamodb` already exists. Please be mindful of this, thank you!

Comment: Will keep that in mind for next time. Sorry about that and thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 0):

If your using the DynamoDb batchWriteitem or another batch insert you need to check the **"UnprocessedItems" Element** in the response. Sometimes batch writes exceed the provisioned write capacity of your table and it will not process all of your inserts, sounds like what is happening here.

You should check the response of your insert and if there are unprocessed items setup a retry and exponential backoff timing strategy in your code. This will allow for the additional items to be inserted until all of your CSV is processed.

Here is the refrerence link for Dynamo [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) if you want to take a closer look at the response elements. Good luck!